# Anaconda python3.5 windows gdal instal

Tags: windows, installation, anaconda, python-3.5, gdal

Trying to install gdal for my anaconda3 python (Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32)

I have tried to follow several guides, but none have worked so far.

I initially tried this guide

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL

I downloaded release-1800-x64-gdal-2-2-1-mapserver-7-0-6.zip from http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1800-x64-gdal-2-2-1-mapserver-7-0-6.zip and unpacked the folder to C:.

I then added the bin folder in the unpacked folder to the user environment variable. The guide then tells you to add the data folder to a new environment variable called GDAL_DATA, but there was no data folder in the unpacked folder. There was however a gdal-data folder within the bin folder, so i added that path instead. Another step i took that wasn't included in the guide was to add bin\gdal\python to the PYTHONPATH environment variable since python wasn't able to find osgeo otherwise.

when i try `from osgeo import gdal` in python i get the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\release-1800-x64-gdal-2-2-1-mapserver-7-0-6\bin\gdal\python\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\release-1800-x64-gdal-2-2-1-mapserver-7-0-6\bin\gdal\python\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Another method that i have tried is downloading the .msi installers,gdal-202-1800-x64-core.msi and GDAL-2.2.1.win-amd64-py3.4.msi from the same site as above. I install the core components first which gives me a C:\programfiles\GDAL folder that i add to the user environment variables. I also add the an environment variable called GDAL_DATA (C:\programfiles\GDAL\gdal-data) and GDAL_DRIVER_PATH (C:\programfiles\GDAL\gdalplugins).

running `gdalinfo --version` in the command window gives `GDAL 2.2.1, released 2017/06/23` so that seems to work, but getting it to work with python is trickier.

I then run the GDAL-2.2.1.win-amd64-py3.4.msi to install the python bindings. I choose install on local drive and add the files within the site-packages folder to the site-packages folder of my python installation.

Trying `from osgeo import gdal` in python gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\release-1800-x64-gdal-2-2-1-mapserver-7-0-6\bin\gdal\python\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\release-1800-x64-gdal-2-2-1-mapserver-7-0-6\bin\gdal\python\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Same as before. I do notice that the .msi installer only goes up to python 3.4 and i have python 3.5.

**So the question is:**
Is my version of python incompatible with gdal or is there some way of getting this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already use Anaconda (or Miniconda) there is no need to install GDAL from a different source. If you solely installed those GDAL versions from gisinternals for use with Python i would suggest the following:

- Revert the guide you used, so uninstall them and remove the GDAL_DATA system variable all together.
- Update Conda to a recent version (4.3.x), the recent versions have better support for the activation scripts needed to set the GDAL_DATA upon activation of a Conda environment. (use `conda update conda -n root` to update).
- Install GDAL by using Conda, this will ensure that you get the compatible binaries (hence avoid the DLL error). 
  I prefer using `conda install gdal -c conda-forge`, which will install GDAL compiled by the Conda-Forge feedstock, but there are other versions as well (https://anaconda.org/search?q=gdal).

The above steps should be sufficient. If you want to use the GDAL command line utilities from the console, activating the environment you installed GDAL in will make this possible.
One of the benefit of this method is that when you switch to a different Conda environment, Conda will change the GDAL_DATA value to the one from the active environment. This allows you to mix and match different GDAL versions without any conflicts.

Comment: Solved the problem. A bit of extra info; I had also tried `conda install gdal`, but i got version incompatibility messages. Can i assume that the conda update (i already had version 4.3.21) is only for the environment switching and that specifying the source for the download in `conda install gdal -c conda-forge` is what gives you the correct gdal files?